# Is it possible to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=1+ax^my^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with the following equation,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+ax^my^2$

I had solution for $m=1$ using Mathematica. I need to find a general solution for $m$.

The equation can be rewritten by parametrizeing $y=\frac{u}{u'}$ as $u''+ax^mu=0$; i want declare that problem i introduced is a simplified form from  such equation!

I need absolute solution (not approximate) for the general case. And its OK if the solution is in special functions (because, actually, its the only way to do it).

Can anyone here help me please?

Thank you guys

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+1+%2B+a+x%5Em+y%5E2

Comment: @arthur holy moly! :O I wonder if there is a simplification if we take ${m \in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Have you considered trying maybe a power series based method? Don't know whether it'll lead to much useful for this specific ODE but maybe worth a try

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose - m as an integer did not help. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+1+%2B+a+x%5Em+y%5E2+%2C+m+is+integer

Comment: Rewrite $y'-ax^my^2=1$. The homogeneous case is a Bernoulli differential equation with a well known solution. Then you'll have to find a particular solution... this will be difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+ax^my^2=1+R(x)y^2$$
This is Riccati ODE. The usual method to solve it is the change of function :
$$y(x)=-\frac{u'}{R(x)u(x)}=-\frac{u'}{ax^mu(x)}$$
$y'=-\frac{u''}{ax^mu}+m\frac{u'}{ax^{m+1}u}+\frac{u'^2}{ax^mu^2}$

$y'=-\frac{u''}{ax^mu}+m\frac{u'}{ax^{m+1}u}+\frac{u'^2}{ax^mu^2}=1+ax^m\left(-\frac{u'}{ax^mu(x)}\right)^2$

After simplification :
$$-\frac{u''}{ax^mu}+m\frac{u'}{ax^{m+1}u}=1$$
$$u''-\frac{m}{x}u'-ax^mu=0$$
This is a generalized Bessel ODE. The method to transform it into a standard Bessel ODE and solve it is shown in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html. See Eqs. $(6)$ and $(7)$.