# Solve $y'+2xy^2 = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $y'+2xy^2 = 1$

I've tried to test if the equation is exact or if it can be made exact. Nothing worked and then I understood that it's a non-linear equation. I've tried a lot to think of a substitution so that I can do separation of variables but that also didn't work. It's also not even a Bernoulli's equation.

This might be a simple problem for some but I can't get my head around it. Can I please get some hint? I'm not asking for a full solution so please don't close this question. I can't solve it and I need some help doing it on my own.

Comment: Look at this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3761357/399263 it is a Ricatti ODE reducible to Bessel ODE with probably ugly looking solutions...

Comment: @Itachi: as zwim mentions, this very simple looking ODE has a ugly solution! See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27+%2B+2+x+y%5E2+%3D+1 . A direction field plot will show why the analytic solution is not simple.

Comment: Then I think there must be a mistake. This kind of method aren't even talked about in my class. It is indeed an ugly looking solution. Thank you @Moo

Comment: Why not to try a series solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution, just some pointers which might help on the way towards a solution.

This is a Riccati equation which according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%20%2B2xy%5E2%20%3D%201) has solutions in so called [**Airy** and **Bairy** functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) which are defined as solutions to the related family of differential equations.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dy^2} -xy = 0$$

These solutions can not be expressed in elementary functions, but are rather commonly expressed as trigonometric integrals $$Ai(x) = \frac 1 \pi \int_0^\infty \cos\left(\frac{t^3}3 +xt\right)dt$$

Moreover, we can easily see by ocular inspection that there can't be a polynomial solution to our question.

This is because the $y'$ shrinks in order, while $2xy^2$ grows (as compared to $y$).

If we slightly modify the differential equation to $$y' + y^2 = 1$$
This becomes a separable equation:
$$\frac{y'}{(1+y)(1-y)} = 1$$
which we can integrate
$$\int\frac{dy}{(1+y)(1-y)} = \int 1 dx$$

This gives us a hint that exponential functions shall be involved as the left hand sides gives us logarithms in $y$ (after some partial fraction decomposition).

How to handle the $2x$ factor, I don't know. Maybe we can do $\sqrt{2x}$ and a variable substitution of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

To transform the original nonlinear differential equation into a linear one, we make the substitution $y=\varphi\frac{u'}{u}$, where $\varphi$ is a function to be determined. Thus,
$$
y'+2x^2y=1 \implies \varphi'\frac{u'}{u}+\varphi\frac{u''}{u}+(2x\varphi^2-\varphi)\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}=1. \tag{1}
$$
Choosing $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{2x}$, we eliminate the nonlinear term $\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}$ from $(1)$, which then we can rewrite as
$$
-\frac{1}{2x^2}\frac{u'}{u}+\frac{1}{2x}\frac{u''}{u}=1 \implies xu''-u'-2x^2u=0. \tag{2}
$$
Although not obvious, Eq. $(2)$ is related to [Airy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function),
$$
z''-tz=0, \tag{3}
$$
whose general solution is $z(t)=c_1\text{Ai}(t)+c_2\text{Bi}(t)$.
Indeed, differentiating $(3)$ one obtains
$$
z'''-tz'-z=0 \implies z'''-tz'-\frac{z''}{t}=0 \implies tz'''-z''-t^2z'=0. \tag{4}
$$
One can transform Eq. (2) into Eq. (4) with the substitutions $u(x)=z'(t)$, $t=\sqrt[3]{2}x$. Therefore, the solution to Eq. $(2)$ is
$$
u(t)=c_1\text{Ai}'(\sqrt[3]{2}x)+c_2\text{Bi}'(\sqrt[3]{2}x). \tag{5}
$$
Plugging $(5)$ into $y=\varphi\frac{u'}{u}$, we finally obtain
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}[c_1\text{Ai}''(\sqrt[3]{2}x)+c_2\text{Bi}''(\sqrt[3]{2}x)]}{c_1\text{Ai}'(\sqrt[3]{2}x)+c_2\text{Bi}'(\sqrt[3]{2}x)}=2^{-1/3}\frac{c_1\text{Ai}(\sqrt[3]{2}x)+c_2\text{Bi}(\sqrt[3]{2}x)}{c_1\text{Ai}'(\sqrt[3]{2}x)+c_2\text{Bi}'(\sqrt[3]{2}x)}, \tag{6}
$$
where we used $(3)$ to simplify the numerator of the last fraction.